# How to backup locked apps?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, backup, apk

Device: Huawei Y300
Android: Jelly Bean; no root

I'd  like to backup  apps (their APKs). There are some apps that can't be backuped with ES File Explorer. AppMonster marks them as  locked, and I've read that that's a safety feature. Some apps have this, and they can't be backed up by many backup apps that I've tried so far.

How can I backup these locked apps?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Titanium Backup. It has extra features for rooted devices, but normal app and data backups work fine wihtout root.

Comment: Same apps don't work for me.

Comment: What apks are they?